# Extract values from file using shell script

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu

In this file structure i want to extract the **K-EFFECTIVE** value and export it to an output file. How could I do it using shell script?.
Thanks in advance.

```
                    ...
0          OUTER ITERATIONS COMPLETED AT ITERATION  25, ITERATIONS HAVE CONVERGED
0          K-EFFECTIVE =   1.08760108893
0          BREAKDOWN OF CPU TIME:    
               *********************     
           COUPLING COEFFICIENTS   =    15.80
           SOLUTION INITIALIZATION =     0.46
           OUTER ITERATIONS        =   263.21
           CREATE EDIT FILES       =     0.31
                     ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU `grep` in PCRE mode:

```
grep -oP 'K-EFFECTIVE\s*=\s*\K.*' file > output
```

Comment: thanks for your replay, another question, I have several K-effective values, how do I export them all in the same output file in a column?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Yro the `-o` option should result in one line of output for each matched value i.e. a column of values in the `output` file

Comment: Thanks!, it has been very helpful.